# Где потренировать свои навыки Тестирования на Java с Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

Обучаюсь автоматизации тестирования на Selenium WebDriver /Java
Готов поучаствовать в каких-либо проектах, пусть даже бесплатных. Может быть кто-то может подсказать где можно "набраться опыта"?

Comment: Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск работы и т.п. не по теме сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:
регистрируетесь на github скачиваете любой понравившийся проект (приоритет - чтобы было понятно, что проект делает), устанавливаете и тестируете

Вариант 2:
идите на сайт фриланс (их таких несколько), находите программистов и предлагаете им помощь, только предупредите, что не профи ещё.